# Enterprise Architect 14 element usage instead of element detail

Tags: enterprise-architect

Sparx Systems has released EA v14 and they have changed some basic behavior that has been working for years. 
Double click on a use case in the project browser opens element usage instead of element detail.
Does anybody know how to reenable this options?

Answer (score 1):

In EA version 14 build 1420 i **don't think its possible to re-enable those options**.

The only way is you can dock the properties screen and it will be updated as per you selection.

Where as in EA 13 you can customize that option in **Start -> Preferences -> General -> Double click on browser.**

[image]